# Ubuntu 18.04 Emergency Mode install updates

Tags: dual-boot, mode

> ```
> You are in emergency mode. 
> After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, 
> "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" 
> or ^D to try again to boot into default mode"<
> ```

The output of `sudo blkid` and `cat ../etc/fstab` on my screen:

[image: screenshot]

Don't know how to insert `blkid` and `/etc/fstab` content here.

Answer (score 1):

- boot to GRUB Recovery mode
- choose root access

**type**:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /        # to remount the disk as rw

sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.BAK # backup the fstab file first

sudo pico /etc/fstab              # edit fstab
```

**edit the entry for:**

change the UUID for`/usr/local`, to the UUID shown in `sudo blkid` for `/dev/sdb2`

**note:** having a separate partition for `/usr/local` is very unusual.

Comment: The user _is already running_ a superuser-privileged shell.  It is pictured in the question.  There is no need to reboot or indeed involve GRUB at all.

Comment: @JdeBP I don't understand your point. And how does it change my answer? Everything there will fix the fstab.

Comment: You don't understand how _there is no need to reboot_ relates to your instruction to reboot?

Comment: @JdeBP I have no instruction to reboot. I have instructions to fix the problem from a cold start. It's a **known starting condition**... not some arbitrary emergency stop, where you don't know the actual condition of the machine.